# Experimental confirmation of the finite jump of the occupation number at the Fermi surface

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fermi-liquids

It is a well-known result in Fermi-liquid theory that the occupation number has a finite jump at the Fermi surface. But, is it confirmed experimentally?

[image]

Comment: Is this true even at finite temperature (within Fermi liquid theory)?

Comment: Only at $T =  0$.

Comment: OK, so doesn't that answer your question? Under achievable experimental conditions, with $T>0$, there will not be a finite jump. So then the question would be what does Fermi liquid theory say about the occupation near $k_F$ for small $T\neq 0$?

Comment: Even at finite-$T$ you get a finite jump. It is just that the jump gets sharper and sharper as you lower the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of experimental evidence showing that only a tiny fraction of the electrons close to the Fermi surface participate in the physical properties of a metal.

One of them is the specific heat due to electronic degrees of freedom : at a certain temperature $T$, only electrons within a typical energy of $k T$ around the Fermi level can be excited by thermal fluctuations. The total number of these "available" electrons is hence proportional to $T$, if each one of them carries a typical energy of order $k T$, you get a total thermal energy proportional to $T^2$. Deriving this quantity with respect to temperature you get a specific heat linear in $T$, which is what is seen at low temperatures.